# How to flag series of votes

Tags: support, downvotes, serial-voting

Few minutes before Four answers([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605674/how-to-subtract-a-year-and-a-day-from-the-datetime/37605693#37605693),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780842/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime/37780857#37780857),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820506/using-same-datatable-for-pagemethod-and-webmethod-in-asp-net/32820561#32820561),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150693/can-i-use-sign-in-content-property-of-control/34150729#34150729))(unfortunately these ware the top voted answers for me) ware down-voted by someone. Is there any possibility to flag/report such series votes(up - down) to get attention of the moderators.

Comment: @NSNoob : thanks for the response, Will it give any punishment or notice for the down-voter?

Comment: See updated answer, If the perpetrator has shown such behavior before and continues to do so, Mods will investigate themselves. They have tools to find out evidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SE does not need this feature because there is already a way for system to detect malicious voting patterns and correct the reputation accordingly.

If someone serial up-votes and down-votes your answers/questions, you have to wait for at least 24 hours. When the script is run, your reputation will be corrected to pre-malicious-voting level.

Read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) for help.

Quoting from the same page:

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your
>   posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes
>   to be invalid and removes them.

What to do when you think you are victim of serial voting?

> If you see very unusual votes being targeted at your account, don't
>   worry about it. You should wait at least 24 hours after noticing
>   before becoming concerned, as the automated system should detect it
>   and reverse it for you. If, after 24 hours, you do not see any fix to
>   your reputation, please contact the team using the "contact us" form
>   located at the bottom of any page.

What happens to the perpetrator(s):

> If such a voting pattern continues to happen between two users
>   mutually or from one user towards another, or otherwise falls outside
>   of normal voting patterns, moderators and/or developers may
>   investigate the matter; intentionally voting merely to reduce or
>   inflate another user's reputation is considered abuse.

The exact nature and rules of the reversal script are kept in secret to avoid potential abusers from finding work-arounds. Relax, your reputation will be back by tomorrow.

Comment: Fine, Is there any limit for such votes? How many votes i can cast to a single user? Will the script detects daily votes

Comment: @un-lucky as evident from the help page, system only concerns itself with votes cast in a short span of time. For example, you can't go around upvoting someone's five posts within one minute, system will detect it as malicious

Comment: is that limit is `5`. `you can't go around upvoting someone's five posts within one minute`. Oh god he may be aware of this he castes only `4`

Comment: @un-lucky it is not, that was just an example. Don't worry about it, we all have been victims of serial downvoting and we all get our rep back. The exact details of script are kept in secret to avoid potential abusers to circumvent around it

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time with me for explaining this.

Comment: Glad to inform you that, i got those reputations back

Comment: It doesn't work. I got serial downvoted last week and it was never reversed and I just got serial downvoted again.

Comment: @Hack-R Then follow the due process which says `If, after 24 hours, you do not see any fix to your reputation, please contact the team using the "contact us" form located at the bottom of any page.` Explain your situation and Stack Exchange employees will get it fixed for you if it is indeed serial voting.